# Serve concurrent users with Flask and gunicorn

Tags: python, flask, gunicorn

I'm using a flask app behind gunicorn server. I would like my app to serve concurrent request. For testing this purpose, I've written a small test:

```
 @app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
 def get_tasks_test():
     time.sleep(10)
     return jsonify({'test is working'})
```

I start gunicorn with:

> gunicorn app:app localhost:8000 --reload --worker-connections 100
>   --worker-class gevent

now i send some concurrent requests simultaneously, and expect the server to respond for all of them in around 10 seconds (because of the sleep i've set)
however, the server seems to wait 10 seconds between each request, which refutes the concurrency in my opinion.
Am I right? what should i do to make my server handle concurrency?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think `--worker-connections` is what you want. It is using gevent which is blocked by your `time.sleep(10)`.

What you want instead is `--workers 4` which will open up 4 worker processes. That will allow you to serve 4 simultaneous requests. I wouldn't put this at 100 like you have for worker connections instead the general rule of thumb is `2-4x the number of processor cores`. So if you have a quad core machine that has hyper threading enabled you can do `32` workers.

Finally, you can pass `--threads 4` to have each of those processes open 4 threads to process requests on. **Be careful not to create too many processes with a lot threads. This is not an unlimited resource.**

References

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html?highlight=--worker-connections#workers

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/stable/design.html#choosing-a-worker-type